# Invoke method on every object in a list, or pass list of objects to method and return new list?

Tags: c#, list

This might be too general of a question so let me add some specifics:

I have a list of entity objects that I need to transform into another object using AutoMapper.

I already have a method that takes an entity as an argument and returns another object after calling AutoMapper's `.Map()`

**My questions is which is less expensive?**

**-Calling my pre-existing method on each entity from the list?**

**Using something like `foreach` or `.Select(x => transformer.transform(x))`**

or

**-Passing the list of entities to a new method that does the foreach and then returns a new list**

Is there a general rule for this?

Comment: My every day dilemma !

Comment: "To linq or not to linq, that is the question!"

Comment: They are equally little expensive. Both are cheap. Note that `.Select(x => transformer.transform(x))` can also be written `.Select(transformer.transform)`, then the `Func<,>` instance will reference the `tranform` method directly, instead of referencing an anonymous function. But it is equally cheap, just prettier in my opinion.

Comment: I always keep in mind, calling an additional function/method takes extra time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each approach you listed would have a very low overhead. I'd go for the most readable, which IMO is with `Select`. To do otherwise is [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

```
IList<NewT> newList = oldList.Select(transformer.transform).ToList();
```

(`x => transformer.transform(x)` can be written as simply `transformer.transform` in a context like this, since the method is compatible with the `Func<,>` that `Select` needs, credit to [Jeppe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096690/invoke-method-on-every-object-in-a-list-or-pass-list-of-objects-to-method-and-r/19096839#comment28233304_19096690) for noticing that here)

If, however, you have profiled your app and found that you are spending a significant amount of time with this LINQ code (not just in the `transform` part), the fastest approach is probably to write out a `for` loop yourself (whether inline or in another method shouldn't matter much, I'd expect the JITter to inline this at runtime, or have such a small overhead that it doesn't matter).

```
IList<NewT> newList = new List<NewT>(oldList.Count);
for (int i = 0; i < oldList.Count; i++)
    newList[i] = transformer.transform(oldList[i]);
```

However, I find this highly unlikely, as pulling entities from a DB and automapping are glacially slow compared to LINQ.

Comment: `+1` for initializing the `new List<>` with the known `Count`. You might as well use an array (why, you cast it to the interface `IList<>`, so a simple array is an `IList<>`).

Comment: Appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop over the list you want to map. AutoMapper is able to convert a list to an other list.
For example; if you mapped TSource to TDestination, than you can convert IEnumerable < TSource> to IEnumerable< TDestination>.

Check here: http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays

Comment: Thanks for the automapper tip!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your answer is going to hinge on the usage of the list - are you going to be treating it as an `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` or `List<T>` - the closer to a concrete arraylike structure you need the list to be, the more expensive it is. If you're likely to be using LINQ to possibly reduce the number of calls through the AutoMapper transform...

So, do you really want to transform from `List<T>` to `List<T>` is the question that should guide you here.